# How do I preserve column widths when pasting a Google Doc table into Gmail?

Tags: gmail, google-docs

Say I have the following table in Google Docs:

> [image]

(Yes it's a table, the borders are just set to 0.)

If I try to copy it and paste it into Gmail, it gets rid of all the column spacing:

> [image]

(Notice how there is almost no space between "Special Event" and "WWDC".)

How can I paste the table such that it preserves my original column widths?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why it's the case, but the trick is to **copy 2 empty lines before the table**.

For example, if you try copying just one empty line before the Google docs table:

> [image]

You'll end up with squished table in Gmail when you paste it:

> [image]

If you instead copy 2 lines before the table in Google Docs:

> [image]

You'll end up with a nicely formatted table in Gmail upon pasting it:

> [image]

After it's pasted into gmail, you can delete the two empty lines above the table.